# Calling of a method from another binding in a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, combobox, command

I have a combobox which I want to call a method from MainViewModel but it binds to EmployeesOverviewViewModel. Is it possible to do this? if yes - how?

### Here is my code for the combobox

```
<ComboBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Text="Select Employees" DataContext="{Binding EmployeesOverviewViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}" Name="employeeComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="{Binding ElementName=employeeComboBox, Path=ActualWidth}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I have thought about using Command but I couldn't figure out the binding problem.

BR

Comment: Does the window/panel/page containing the combobox have its data context set to an instance of the MainViewModel? If so you could use a binding which looks up the parent and binds to its datacontext.

Comment: the window with the combobox has mainviewmodel as datacontext but the combobox has employeesoverviewmdel som datacontext

Comment: I have added an answer with an example of how to bind to a parents data context.

Answer (score 1):

if your MainViewModel is anywhere is the visual tree as the DataContext, then you can achieve what you want with RelativeSource in your CommandBinding for your ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

In expanding on my comment to the original post. Shown below is an example of how to bind to the data context of the parent.

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
    AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SomeCommand}"
```

Set the path to command on the viewmodel you want to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

Do both ViewModels know each other? Then the `EmployeesOverviewViewModel` could provide an delegate that you would execute and the `MainWindowViewModel` could use this delegate to "bind" it to its method. (edit: it would be enough if the `MainWindowViewModel` knows the `EmployeesOverviewViewModel`)

Otherwise you could try to use a binding using `FindAncestor` and try to get the `MainWindowView`. The problem then would be that you don't just need the view itself but its `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have two realistic approaches.

1) if your view can see a suitable instance of MainViewModel, you should be able to bind to a command or whatever you need on that by using StaticResource or DynamicResource. I see you're using a StaticResource to find the viewmodel providing the ComboBox's items, would something similar work for finding MainViewModel?

2) if your view can't see a MainViewModel, but your viewmodel can, get the viewmodel to expose a suitable command or method and just have that call MainViewModel's version. This is cleaner, as then your EmployeesOverviewView doesn't have to know anything about MainViewModel at all.

I'd prefer option 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a MultiValueConverter. I show you a small sample.

I have a window with 3 CheckBox:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="300" Width="400" mc:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:WpfApplication7="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7" d:DesignHeight="371" 
    d:DesignWidth="578" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Window.Resources>
        <WpfApplication7:MultiBooleanConverter x:Key="multiBooleanConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Content="Hallo">
            <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=multiBooleanConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="checkBox1" Path="IsChecked"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="checkBox2" Path="IsChecked"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </CheckBox.IsChecked>
       </CheckBox>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,120,0,0" x:Name="checkBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The MultiValueConverter is declared like that:

```
public class MultiBooleanConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Cast<bool>().Any(b => b);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object[] returnValue = new object[targetTypes.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < targetTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            returnValue[i] = (bool)value;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```